# SW recomendation - a tool to admin apache localhosts and mysql database/users?

Tags: apache2, software-recommendation, mysql, php, virtualhost

I need software recommendation - a tool to admin apache virtual hosts and hosts file and probably mysql database creation(not most impotant) and probably mysql users with access to it (all sites running on localhost)?

I known how to configire it but in need of GUI panel. It should be free and comply this minimal needs. It can be php application but due to security risks better system gui.

Sorry, I luck this point of administration, always doing configuring in text configs, but now need to simply create new websites and db for it in a simply way. Also this tool should manage dns or hosts file as it only for localhost.

Update: my installation not belongs to lamp or xamp, but if possible to use something from there its good

Update: I have try few ISP virtual hosting panels, they make virtual hosts isolated and with different users - opposite to what I wan - one user, one apache, simply many virtual hosts.

Update: I can add *.localhost to /etc/hosts, so creation of hosts not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a script to create virtualhosts. It doesn't control hosts/dns but /etc/hosts contains *.localhost wildcard so match any subdomain. Use zenity for gui, so terminal not necessary, on development server where ide placed its a good choice.

Basic of script is template for virtualhost configuration:

```
cat >$TMPHOST$HOST <<EOF
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot $DIR
    ServerName  $HOST.localhost
    ServerAlias $HOST.localhost
    <Directory "$DIR">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
EOF
```

It's on github https://github.com/LeonidMew/CreateVirtualHost

Readme:

> Simple bash script to create apache2 virtualhost for localhost. Can be
>   used for public sub domains on developer server with changes "replace
>   .localhost".
>
> Tested on Ubuntu, but should work where dependency met.
>
> Not for production, for development purposes only.
>
> Use zenity for gui and pkexec for root permissions.